# how to render a html page using cloudflare workers

Tags: javascript, html, cloudflare, worker

I have created a route https://bewithrits.tech and when i am using https://bewithrits.tech/ then it will render the desired page but when i am adding https://bewithrits.tech/? or https://bewithrits.tech/?fb then it will give the error Error 1000
DNS pointed to prohibited IP wanted to implement in the given route not wanted to use
https://bewithrits.tech/* .
here is my tried code

```
const html1 = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
    <style>
      .button {
        background-color: rgba(162, 51, 79, 0.3);
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #a2334f;
        width: 150px;
        border: none;
        padding: 13px 26px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 19px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0.7;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="" class="button"> Know More </a>
  </body>
</html>
`


const html2 = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
    <style>
      .button {
        background-color: rgba(162, 51, 79, 0.3);
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #a2334f;
        width: 150px;
        border: none;
        padding: 13px 26px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 19px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0.7;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="" class="button"> Know More </a>

    <p>queryy</p>
  </body>
</html>
`
addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
 console.log(request.url)
 console.log(request.url.includes('/?'))

  if(request.url==='https://bewithrits.tech' ||request.url==='https://bewithrits.tech/'){
 return new Response(html1, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://bewithrits.tech',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, HEAD, POST, GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
          'X-Requested-With, Authorization,' + 'Content-Type, Accept',
      },
    })

  }
  
  else if(request.url.includes('/?')){
     return new Response(html2, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://bewithrits.tech',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'OPTIONS, HEAD, POST, GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
          'X-Requested-With, Authorization,' + 'Content-Type, Accept',
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your web server IP address as the A record. You are pointing the A record to Cloudflare's server which you should not do.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029779472-Troubleshooting-Cloudflare-1XXX-errors#error1000

Answer (score 0):

You need the trailing `*` if you want to match URLs with query parameters (URLs with a `?` in them). Unfortunately, there's no way around this.

This is a known problem with the way Cloudflare Workers routing patterns are interpreted right now. We would like to change it, but it's tricky because we don't want to break any existing workers that depend on the existing behavior.